# Is it possible to access whole screen using WebRTC getusermedia and HTML5?

Tags: javascript, html5-video, html5-canvas, webrtc

I am trying my hands to share my screen locally through the browser.
is it possible to share screen using getusermedia or HTML5 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Screen sharing with WebRTC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616449/screen-sharing-with-webrtc)

Answer (score 2):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616449/screen-sharing-with-webrtc). Effectively, the answer is "Not yet, but probably eventually, though nobody knows when."

Comment: Thanks, But is it possible to use Gstreamer and webRTC to do it

Comment: No idea about GStreamer. But eventually, you probably will be able to use WebRTC to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Screen sharing can be done via getUserMedia with the chrome.tabCapture API, but currently only on the Chrome Dev channel: see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13616449/screen-sharing-with-webrtc).

Comment: Thanks I saw your posting about HTML5 Tab sharing, it was really helpful. But is it possible to use Gstreamer and webRTC to do it.