# When will Opera resupport the gerUserMedia API?

Tags: opera, webrtc, getusermedia

Opera was one of the first browsers to start supporting getUserMedia and WebRTC in version 12, but they dropped support in version 15 and it hasn't come back since.

Opera 15's announcement stated "getUserMedia isn’t hooked up yet in Opera 15 and will be come back in a future release."

Comment: Hopefully soon. Once Opera and Safari get support, that'll leave only IE as the odd man out. (Although I hear that IE11 supports WebRTC, but I haven't confirmed that myself yet.)

Answer (score 0):

Opera 18 supports it. You can test it here: http://www.thinstallsoft.com/opera-next-portable/

Unfortunately it is not correctly reported on caniuse: http://caniuse.com/#feat=rtcpeerconnection

Comment: I have Opera 25.0.1614.71, and it still shows permission desktopCapture not found. Screen sharing is still not supported in any of the Opera versions.

Comment: @var17 GetUserMedia is something different then Chrome Extensions specific desktopCapture API and therefore not related. You can offcourse use it as a source FOR WebRTC :) Maybe in the future it is supported: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13636424/951001

Comment: Thanks @KoalaBear. So we wait until Opera supports chromeMediaConstraint. Also Opera does not supports any other API that could allow screen share for now. So does IE. I could not find a way to screen share on IE. ORTC also has established only peer to peer RTC